# Is a children/ child tag relevant?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are two questions:

https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/132/which-dog-breeds-are-the-most-suitable-for-families-with-small-children

[How do I introduce our dog to a brand new baby](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/75/how-do-i-introduce-our-dog-to-a-brand-new-baby)

I created a children tag. Given pets, by definition, are in domestic relationships with people; should we have a children tag?

Comment: I think we are surely going to get this kind of questions so keeping this tag would be good.

Comment: Maybe the tag wiki excerpt should clarify that this tag is about human children, not about the pets offspring (just to avoid future misuse).

Comment: I would say don't question the existence of tags till we hit at least mid-public beta.  Synonyms?  Yes. Existence? Wait a bit.

Answer (score 8):

As the creator of the [babies](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/babies) tag, I agree that we need a tag for children.  However, I don't think babies and children are both needed, so I retagged my question with the [children](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children) tag instead.

Should we synonymize [babies](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/babies) with [children](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children)

My reasoning is if we don't do it now, someone is just going to recreate babies and it will be easier when there are only a few questions.

Comment: Yes I agree synonymize child and baby/babies with children

Comment: While there might be slight differences in those tags, I agree that synonimizing those tags would be good. People who are experienced with babies and animals are likely to have experience with children and animals, too.

Comment: Children are anything from 6 to about 12 so I think that they should stay separate. Whereas over excited dogs would be fine for children who know how to say no, they would be a bad choice entirely for babies!

Comment: Why not have a `children-and-babies` tag? I don't think it hurts to make it a little longer to make it clear both are included. That way the tag would come up with autocomplete whichever they started typing as well.

Answer (score 6):

Ah, I would say "YES". Parents fear how there children can be saved from pets or what measures should a parent take before let his child mix freely with the pets or what kind of pets can be allowed to be with a children in an outing etc. There can also be various other reasons which I can't think of now. As children are a specific area of concern while meeting with pets, this tag is very relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a more generic [family-interaction](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/family-interaction) tag.

Think about it this way, would you want a Tweet about a question with the main tag being [children](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children)? Maybe, maybe not.

I think family-interaction is a better description for all forms of family interaction with pets.

Comment: I think this is a great suggestion. "Children" is probably going to be of limited utility. This proposal covers that, and expands the scope of the tag without being too broad.